# createChooser demo app in Android

Tags: android

I am trying createChooser() method.When I run this code why it show **"No apps can perform this action."** please help me.

```
btnFirst.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Choose An Application"));

            }
        });
```

**my AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.intent_coockbook.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity 
            android:name="Second">

            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.android.Action"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no action in the Intent you've created, so there cant be any registered intent filters. See [Intent(android.content.Context, java.lang.Class)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E%29). Look over the [Intent Structure](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#IntentStructure) docs for a better understanding. It also lists some common action/data pairs.

To show a chooser to open a url you'd use something like

```
Intent i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse("http://example.org"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Open example with..."));
```

Of course, you can create your own custom Intents and Intent Filters, this is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

See below link :-

[What is createChooser when I have to use Intents? What I could do with this method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294308/what-is-createchooser-when-i-have-to-use-intents-what-i-could-do-with-this-meth)

http://www.yogeshblogspot.com/android-createchooser-demo-app-yogeshblogspot-com/

Comment: bro @Hemant Chand Dungriyal I have seen this link.But i have not solve yet.please help me

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
Intent _intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        _intent.setType("text/plain");
        _intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Text You want to share."
                + "https://www.abc.com/");
        _intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(_intent, "Hi, I am using Android"
                + "https://abc.com/"));
```

Comment: I want two class option.Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class)...@Dev Carlsberg